# how to write bat file to process all files include sub directory, and output them with the same directory structure to another directory?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file to process all file under a directory, and output to another directory

this is the codes in the bat file

```
@set dir1=mulit-simp\
@set dir2=mulit-trad\
@cd /d %~dp0
@if not exist %dir1% md %dir1%
@if not exist %dir2% md %dir2%
@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir %dir1%*.* /b') do @opencc.exe --input="%dir1%%%i" --output="%dir2%%%i"
@echo.
@echo Done!
@echo.
@pause
```

but this code can't process files in the sub directory
How could I process the sub directory files, and output them with the same directory structure to another directory?
thx for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DIR /S` option would give you the entire folder hierarchy. And you also want the `/A-D` option to suppress folders from the output. Type `HELP DIR` or `DIR /?` for more info.

However, instead of using `FOR /F` with `DIR`, I recommend using `FOR /R`. Type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` for more info. Also see http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm for easier to understand explanation of the `FOR` command.

Either way, you also need to create all of the destination folders. The easiest way to do that is to use `XCOPY /T /E` to create the destination folders prior to processing the files.

Some additional tips:

- Simply put `@echo off` at the top instead of prefixing every command with `@`
- `ECHO.` has been widely used for years, but it can actually fail to work properly. Safer to use `ECHO(` instead.
- You probably don't want the environment variable you define to hang around after the batch is finished. Putting `SETLOCAL` at the top will make the variables temporary and they will exist only until the batch file finishes, or until `ENDLOCAL` is executed. Given that you are using `PAUSE` at the end, I suspect you are running the batch file by double clicking on the file or a shortcut. If so, then the command window closes at the end, and the variables disappear along with it. Then `SETLOCAL` is not needed, but it is still probably a good practice to get into anyway.

Here is the finished code with all of the suggestions. *EDIT - The original code did not work. Altered to address tiance's comments*

```
@echo off
setlocal
set dir1=mulit-simp
set dir2=mulit-trad
cd "%~dp0"

:: Replicate tree
if not exist "%dir1%" md "%dir1%"
if not exist "%dir2%" md "%dir2%"
xcopy /t /e "%dir1%" "%dir2%"

:: Get length of absolute path of %dir1%
<nul set /p "=%cd%\%dir1%" >getLength.tmp
for %%F in (getLength.tmp) do set len=%%~zF
del getLength.tmp

:: Process the files
for /r "%dir1%" %%F in (*) do (
  set "src=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  opencc.exe --input="!src!" --output="%dir2%!src:~%len%!"
  endlocal
)
echo(
echo Done!
echo(
pause
```

Comment: it's very kind of you :) but i didn't get the right result with your code. All my files output under the fold mulit-trad. For example, the file in mulit-simp\myfold\a.txt should be output in mulit-trad\myfold\a.txt, but now it appears in mulit-trad\a.txt.

Comment: xcopy /t /e "%dir1%" "%dir2%"    it returns Invalid Path

Comment: it seems directory can't end with "\" when using xcopy, but I still don't know how to output file in the right sub directory

Comment: @tiance: Sorry about that. My original post was a lame effort. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `XCOPY sourcefolder destinationfolder /E` ?

Comment: thx for answer :) but the important thing is using opencc.exe to process each file under the directory, and input,output argument can not be the same T_T